# error[E0277]: the trait bound `xcm::v3::SendError: PalletError` is not satisfied

Tags: substrate-node-template, xcm, error

I'm attempting to utilize the XCM error within the context of my pallet's error handling, but I'm facing this problem.

[image]

The error which i'm using

```
#[pallet::error]
pub enum Error<T, I = ()> {

    SendingError(SendError),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how [pallet-xcm](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/aabed6757e26e21ce06dd59946a17b72f349185e/polkadot/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs#L449-L457) handles the conversion of the SendError to pallet errors. This might help you with your problem.